# scrollTop is not set in Angular application

Tags: angularjs, angular

i have a div with the name #taget

```
   <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10">
     <div class="quantity-buttons"  #target>
      ....
```

in the code i am refrenceing it like this

```
 @ViewChild('target') target;
```

on a button click i am trying to set the scrollTop property to some value.

```
 this.target.nativeElement.scrollTop  = 200;
```

but it has no effect. I can see scrollTop = 0 before and after the above line of code is executed.

Comment: not exactly an answer but i used 
https://github.com/Nolanus/ng2-page-scroll
to fix my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@ViewChild('target') public myScrollContainer: ElementRef;
```

and then,

```
let nativeElement = this.myScrollContainer.nativeElement;
nativeElement.scrollTop = 200;
```

Comment: scrollTop remains 0 never changed to 200

Comment: how do you say so?

Comment: are you applying this via a method?

Comment: so i have a break point on 200 line. before the break-point is hit scrollTop is 0 and after the execution it remains 0

Comment: just check via the css sometimes ts files does not show

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157492/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-raas-masood).